# How do I translate theme settings?

Tags: i18n-l10n, 8

How do you translate custom theme settings in Drupal 8?

I use `hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter` to add custom settings to a theme. One setting is the text string (e.g. 'Menu') to display beside the menu icon for a responsive menu. How can I integrate with the configuration translation system to allow the text to be translated?

All of the examples I have found describe how to translate a custom module's settings. I have not found any examples about how to translate a themes's settings, but there are a few hints in the Drupal code base that suggest it should be possible to create a `THEME.config_translation.yml` file.

I have taken a lead from [this article](http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2014-may-26/drupal-8-multilingual-tidbits-16-configuration-translation-development) on Gábor Hojtsy's blog and created the following files:

- `config/install/mytheme.settings.yml`
- `config/schema/mytheme.schema.yml`
- `mytheme.config_translation.yml`

The schema is valid (tested using [Configuration Inspector](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_inspector)) and I have managed to get a Translate button for my theme's settings to show up on the Configuration translation admin page (`/admin/config/regional/config-translation`). That's as far as I've got.

I don't know what to use for base_route_name in `mytheme.config_translation.yml`. Here's what I have:

```
mytheme.settings:
  title: 'My Theme Settings'
  base_route_name: system.theme_settings
```

For `base_route_name` I used `system.theme_settings` which results in a Translate button that links to `/admin/appearance/settings/translate`, but clicking on it leads to an Access denied, I assume because there is no translate page for theme settings. Also, I think the `base_route_name` should be `system.theme_settings_theme` and the Translate button should map to `/admin/appearance/settings/mytheme/translate`, but I get an error when I try that.

Am I on the right track? How would I go about creating a `/admin/appearance/settings/mytheme/translate` page and integrate it with the config translation system?

Comment: config/install/LANGCODE/mytheme.settings.yml

Comment: I'm getting the same error as above. How to enable translation for theme settings?

Comment: check my answer here - it helped me to translate theme settings https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/283930/50320

Comment: Also, important to understand the difference between `string` and `text`. A `string` does not translate, while `text` can be translated. I haven't experimented much with this other than fixing a custom module where my setting was being translated every time I enabled/disabled a module and translations were updated. I do believe that the addition of `translatable: true` is also important.

Comment: Admittedly not a fully qualified answer to OP's question but based on the example string 'Menu' they mentioned it's good to remember that all strings of Drupal core are always available on a site for translation. In other words: until your custom code uses only strings already used by core itself they'll be translatable. For example, string 'Menu' is [definitely included in core](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/hu/translate?project=drupal&release=all&search=Menu).