# D8 How to create custom configurational form translatable?

Tags: 8, forms, i18n-l10n

I am new to Drupal 8 Custom Translation.
I am working on a custom module with a backend form from where user can add some textual inputs.

The Site is multilingual, so I need to have this backend form translatable.

May I know the steps or any links from where I can get an idea where to start for translatable configuration form/page where user can add textual inputs for each languages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You need a schema yaml file in the module folder `/config/schema` to make configuration forms translatable:

> #### What are schema files used for?
>
> 1. The primary use case schema files were introduced for is
>      multilingual support. We need to have a tool to identify all
>      translatable strings in your shipped configuration so when you ship
>      with your own settings as well as default Views, additional user
>      roles, menu items, etc. we can offer those up for translation as part
>      of your module/theme release on http://localize.drupal.org. The
>      nesting levels and types would be enough for this use case.
> 2. We also use schemas to provide actual translation forms for
>      configuration based on your data. This use case is where types gain
>      more importance and labels become crucial. The core *Configuration
>      translation* module uses schemas to generate translation forms and
>      save translations. The two most important built-in translatable types
>      are 'label' for one-line text input and 'text' for multiline text
>      input.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/1905070

Answer (score 3):

It can take quite a while until you get all the naming correct. For people struggling with this, we've published a module with a working example here: https://github.com/VITObelgium/drupal-boilerplate

> This module provides an example of how to create a configuration form in a custom module and make it translatable out-of-the-box.

Comment: Can you create an example for a theme, please? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/193919/7177