# How can I translate config entity fields?

Tags: 8

The question is fairly straight forward. I have several config entities with various fields.

I haven't found a way to translate config entity fields in the Drupal 8 documentation(or maybe I haven't looked hard enough, both are a strong possibility).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a schema of the type `config_entity`.

See for example the one for the node type config entity:

*/node/config/schema/node.schema.yml:*

```
node.type.*:
  type: config_entity
  label: 'Content type'
  mapping:
    name:
      type: label
      label: 'Name'
    type:
      type: string
      label: 'Machine-readable name'
    description:
      type: text
      label: 'Description'
    help:
      type: text
      label: 'Explanation or submission guidelines'
    new_revision:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Whether a new revision should be created by default'
    preview_mode:
      type: integer
      label: 'Preview before submitting'
    display_submitted:
      type: boolean
      label: 'Display setting for author and date Submitted by post information'
```

Choose for fields you want to make translatable the types `label` and `text`. See also [D8 How to create custom configurational form translatable?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239797/d8-how-to-create-custom-configurational-form-translatable/239817#239817)

Comment: This is a little more complicate than I imagined. Either way, it's seem this is the way. Thanks.